# .net mvc 3 how to work with a small object graph

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, razor

am a real Newbie in asp.net mvc 3 with razor and EntityFramework 4.1
In Order to practice a littel i chose to do a small project wit it.It's an online registration  applicaition with it. Passing simple data to view using ViewBag and relying on Visual Studio for action/view scaffolding was nice. But there is a situation where i'm wondering if i should create a form from scratch and passing each property to action with the same number of  arguments  as the properties (like we would do when using php or spring mvc ), or trust .net MVC to build the graph for me.

I have one to zero-or-one association between User and Profile, one to many between Profile and Registration. Registration have unidirectional one to one with Semester and Semester have many to one with Discipline

```
User         1..0  Profile
Profile         1.*   Registration
Registration 1.1   Semester
Semester     *.1   Discipline
```

i have a place to display the Disciples and when a use clicks on the register links it takes to `/Registration/Create/{DisciplineID}` page where i select the appropriates semesters to render as dropdownlist. That Create View is supposed to have almost(aside date_Created and IDs) all the field of User, Profile, Registration(as a semester must be selected from a dropdownlist).

Basically on that View there need be 3 models User, Profile, Registration/Semeter code are available on [pastie](http://pastie.org/3466155)

**Question 1** : how is the best practice for my scenario

**Question 2** : how to have all the model on a single view

**Question 3** is it possible to save the whole object graph?

**EDIT:**

with this data structure i would like to be able to create a form with  most of all needed for my object graph and have insight on how to handle it in `[HttpPost] Create` Action:

```
 /*User Model section*/
   txtbox for email
 /*Profile Model section*/
   txtbox for first_name
   txtbox for last_name
   ....
 /* Registration Section */

   dropdownlistfor Semesters
 /* Payment model section  keeping in mind that one-to-many with Registration*/
    dropdownlist for payment type (maybe from enumeration)
     txtbox for Amount
    ....
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: You may like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336140/including-multiple-views-in-one-page

Comment: @GertArnold are you suggestion i use jquery ajax to submit the form and handle the field one by one at the action or suggesting i render a view in a view?

Comment: The latter, or a similar construct. You can also show/hide parts of your view. The point is to have one page, so you can have one submit, i.e. one atomic transaction.

Comment: thanks what is the name of this method or should i say this way of doing so that i do more research on it?

Comment: I don't think it has a specific name. I only know that we use this pattern frequently for the reasons you describe.

Comment: Ok i feel like i need to read more to embark in this new way , do you mind putting links to resources or clean tutorial? thanks very much. your help is very much appreciated

Comment: I'll check with my colleagues who are more in to this. I'm more the services/data access guy in our projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the user, you can get everything else (assuming the user has a profile).

```
from user in db.User where userid == id select user;
```

From there, you can go to user.Profile or user.Profile.Registrations, from there you get all the registrations and get the semesters from that.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply , my biggest issue is how to use different model in a form. Still can figure it out and all examples i google seem  a little confusing an assume some prerequisite.

Comment: @blacksensei - I'm sorry, you're going to have to write more clearly, as I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: i edited my post to include what i was trying to explain. Sorry if the post is not clair, am not from english speaking language.I hope it's clearer now. thanks